# Route [LaravelInstaller::welcome] not defined

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, mysql-connector

Im facing a problem to my website https://market.dhruvigroup.in , i tired by improving memory linit and setting up new mySql Databased ! anyone can please help me to resolve this problme ?

debug infor enabled in this url to view error log , please visit the mentioned url

**Environment information**

Laravel version : 8.23.1 
Laravel locale : en
Laravel config cached : false
PHP version  : 7.4.16

Comment: post he route which is in  the `web.php `

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the route name is not defined.
You will have to post the contents of your `routes/web.php` for us to be helpful. Does the route appear when you do `php artisan route:list`?

Your routes file must contain something like

```php
Route::get('/', [ControllerName::class, 'methodName'])->name('LaravelInstaller::welcome');
```